# How to change Datatype Entity after generate by scaffold in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, entity-framework, scaffolding

I use `SQLite` with EF for connected database by using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` and
i have a table 'StuffOrder' have a column 'OrderDate' this daatype in database schema 'DATETIME' but when generate convert 'byte[]', how to change datatype ?

**Database schema**

```
CREATE TABLE StuffOrder(
  Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  OrderDate DATETIME NOT NULL
)
```

**EF entity model schema**

```
public class StuffOrders 
{
   public long Id { get; set; }
   public byte[] OrderDate { get; set; }
}
```

> I try change datatype by using `partial` but can't used

**Try Code**

```
public partial class StuffOrders 
{
   public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
}
```

**Tools And NuGet Packages**

- I create Windows form EF 4.8
- Then Create class library .NET Standard 2.0
- Import Class library for EF 4.8
- Microsoft.Data.Sqlite 3.1.0
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.0
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 3.1.0
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 3.1.0

Comment: Does SQLite support DATETIME fields?   I've just googled a few things and it suggests that it doesn't and you should be using TEXT or REAL field types instead.

Comment: Yes, SQLite supported https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/DataTypeMapping.html

Comment: And yet https://sqlite.org/quirks.html (3.2) says it doesn't.

Comment: @Neil I am confused !!!